# Fedora 15: something weird going on with yum

Tags: fedora, yum, repository

I am unsuccessfully trying to install some packages in Fedora 15 using `yum`. Every time I use `yum install` I get this output:

```
[ziga@ziga-CQ56 ~]$ sudo yum install yum-fastestmirror
[sudo] password for ziga: 
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://ayo.freshrpms.net/fedora/linux/15/mirrors-freshrpms error was
14: HTTP Error 404 - Not Found : http://ayo.freshrpms.net/fedora/linux/15/mirrors-freshrpms
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository:    freshrpms. Please verify its path and try again
```

Comment: Have you verified if the url is accessible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have the freshrpms repository installed and enabled, but as http://freshrpms.net/ says, since Fedora 10 almost everything has moved to rpmfusion so you probably don't need it anymore and should switch to rpmfusion.

The specific cause of your error is simply that the freshrpms repository doesn't have any content for Fedora 15.

You can probably get rid of the error by uninstalling freshrpms-release:

```
yum erase freshrpms-release
```

Though you may also want to then install the rpmfusion repository in it's place - see http://rpmfusion.org/ for details on how to do that.

Comment: I really did install freshrpms-release and i did both comands that you sugested, but i still get the same error. There must be something else.

Comment: Check in `/etc/yum.repos.d` and there should be a file that is referencing that repository - find out what package owns that file (with `rpm -qf <file>`) and remove it, or if no package owns it then just remove the file.

Comment: I did it a bit different in /etc/yum.repos.d i found freshrpms.repo file which i opened and changed value of ENABLED to 0. thank you for all the anwsers, we ve solved my problem.

Comment: I comented out some outdated mirrors in /etc/yum.repos.d and i am now fine.

Answer (score 0):

Given you are on F15, you can use:

yum-config-manager --disable freshrpms